# Can we invoke self-defined callback function in the parser of google protocol buffer textformat?

Tags: c++, parsing, data-structures, callback, protocol-buffers

In google protocol buffer, there exists a textual version of message. When parsing this textual message, can we define ourselves the callback functions in order that we could store the information parsed into our own data structure?
For example, if we have defined .proto:

```
message A {
    required string name = 1;
    optional string value =2;
    repeated B bList =3;
}

message B {
    required string name =1;
    optional string value =2;
}
```

And we have textformat message:

```
A {
    name: "x"
    value: "123"
    B {
        name: "y"
        value: "987"
    }
    B {
        name: "z"
        value: "965"
    }
}
```

The protobuf compiler generates the corresponding class named "A", class named "B". The parser can parse this text format into the instance of A. However, if user want to defined our own version of class "A", or there exists a version of A used before. Now as we would like to replace the old exchange format by google protocol buffer, we are willing to parse the google protocol buffer text format version directly into the old data structure. If not, we will have to first of all have the generated data structure (class "A") filled then adapt the  generated data structure to the legacy data structure. It occupies two times the memory than necessary. It can be much less efficient than we wanted.
The traditional method used for integrating a parser is to have a parser that can callback self-defined functors to be accustomed to the new data structure.
So, does there exist a way to inject the self-defined callback function into the text format parser?

Comment: If you are so concerned about memory usage, the Google's C++ protobuf library is probably not your best choice anyway. It focuses more on speed than on conserving RAM, which is quite plentiful on modern non-embedded systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the protobuf TextFormat implementation does not support such extensions.

That said, TextFormat (in at least C++, Java, and Python) is implemented as a self-contained module that operates only on public interfaces (mainly, the reflection interface). You can easily clone it and then make your own modifications to the format, or even write a whole new module in the same style that implements any arbitrary format. For example, many people have written JSON parsers / encoders based on Protobuf reflection, using the TextFormat implementation as a guide.

Comment: Could you please give me an example for JSON parsers / encoders? I appreciate it a lot. I did read a little bit the code of the parser for textformat. It seems that in this parser, it also use the reflection of the Message to fill the Message data structure when reading from the text format file. So, can we implement the reflection interface to replace the version for generated code? In this new implementation, we can add new functions that takes functors for callback?

Comment: Here is an example of a Protobuf JSON codec in C++, although I just found this by Googling and I have no idea if it's any good: https://github.com/shramov/json2pb

You should not be implementing the reflection interface. You should be using the generated code. There is no way to mix hand-written classes with Protobuf generated classes.

Comment: Thanks for that. What if I implement myself a fake Message class as well to be used with the self implemented reflection interface?

Comment: No, you really can't. Protobuf generated classes can only contain other Protobuf generated classes -- any attempt to make them contain hand-written classes will just end in frustration. What you want to do is parse to protobufs and then convert the tree into hand-written classes in a second pass.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My supposition is to implement both Message and Reflection myself. Maybe I need to implement MessageFactory myself as well...It can be complicated...Maybe here, the most important frustrating thing is that we are supposed to correlate protocol and the implemented Message ourselves... In the code base, there is a dynamicMessage type that gives a generic interface for filling the message by compiling the protocol at run-time, but we still need to hard-code the identifier of the protocol to get the Message or fields that we need...well, it is a possible frustrating solution?

Comment: You see in the bottom of the webpage https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial

Comment: Well, you can implement `Message` and `Reflection` yourself and not use the code generator at all, but at that point you've lost almost all of the benefits of using protobufs in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, I have the same doubt as you as well. What about the "dynamic message"?

Comment: `DynamicMessage` doesn't solve your problem. It is really not something you can customize at all. It's just a way to construct `Message` implementations based on descriptors loaded at runtime.